# Why are my CORS requests denied?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors, httprequest

Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3595515/4872477).

I am trying to send a POST request to an API for testing purposes. I keep getting

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '{my local IP}' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Here is the relevant code:

```
function searchSimilar2(){
var base_url = "{request url}"
var send_url = base_url + "{inline arguments}"
var params = '{"size":10, "mediaUrl":"https://cdn.yoox.biz/39/39706632kh_20_f.jpg2"}'

function func(){
    console.log(this.response)
}

var hReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
hReq.open('POST', send_url)
hReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
hReq.onload = func;
hReq.send(params)
```

I omitted the request url and arguments, since I know the problem is not with them.

As per the linked questions answers, I am not using JQuery, and I am running a python SimpleHTTPServer where I am sending this request from. I keep getting this error.

Comment: The server isn't sending back the required CORS headers. Are you loading your page via a `file://` URL?  If so, the browser considers the page and the `http://localhost` server to be two different domains.

Comment: Yes, I read that in the linked question. That is why I am running a simpleHTTPServer and opening the html file that runs the javascript from there.

Comment: Understand that as far as the browser is concerned what has to match is the "http" part ("http" or "https"), the domain **letter for letter**, and the port number. They have to be the same when compared as a string, not just the same IP address.

Comment: It's not completely clear what's going on. Is that ajax request happening from your browser, via the containing page? Or is it somehow running underneath Python in the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the settings of the server, I got this to work.

Part of the url for the requests is "v1/api", and for some reason switching it to "api/v1" made everything work.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header value on the SimpleHttpServer response.  The header value will need to contain the hostname or IP of the requesting application.  Alternatively, you can set the "*" wildcard value to allow all origins, but you should only do that if you actually want to allow all origins as it creates a bit of a XSS vulnerability:

```
//allow single origin
self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://yourapp.com')
self.end_headers()
```

-OR-

```
//allow all origins
self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*') 
self.end_headers()
```